# How to preserve random numbers in Haskell iteration?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to calculate growing list with random number.
The basic code is here:

```hs
import System.Random

randint :: IO Int
randint = randomRIO (0,1)

type Generation = [Int]

gnext :: Generation -> IO Generation
gnext g = flip (:) g <$> randint
```

`gnext` can be more complex.

Now following code behaved as expected:

```hs
test1 = do
  let b0 = []
  b1 <- gnext b0
  b2 <- gnext b1
  b3 <- gnext b2
  b4 <- gnext b3
  return [b0, b1, b2, b3, b4]
```

```hs
ghci> test1
[[],[0],[1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1,0]]
```

We can see the n-th list has the (n-1)-th list in its cdr part.

On the other hand, following code failed (because of lazy evaluation, I think).

```hs
test2 = sequence $ take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])
```

```hs
ghci> test2
[[],[0],[0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1,0]]
```

This result is completely random.

How can I rewrite `test1` code by `test2` style?
Thank you.

Comment: I think it's easier if you first generate the maximum-length list using e.g. `replicateM 5 randint` and then you take the prefixes `inits <$> ...`. Generating an infinite list is tricky when `IO` actions are around, since you don't want all of them to actually run.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with `sequence $ take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])`?

Let's reduce `iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])`:

```
iterate (gnext =<<) (return []) =>
[ return []
, gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
, ...
]
```

Next reduce `take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])`:

```
take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return []) =>
[ return []
, gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
, gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
]
```

And finally, reduce `sequence $ take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])`:

```
sequence $ take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return []) =>
sequence [ return []
         , gnext =<< return []
         , gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
         , gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
         , gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
         ]
```

which equivalent to:

```
do
    b0 <- return []
    b1 <- gnext =<< return []
    b2 <- gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
    b3 <- gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
    b4 <- gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
    return [b0, b1, b2, b3, b4]
```

As you can see, this is not what you want, and lazy evaluation has nothing to do with it.

You can solve this problem with the state monad:

```
gnextM :: StateT Generation IO Generation
gnextM = do
    g0 <- get
    g1 <- liftIO $ gnext g0
    put g1
    return g1

test2 = flip evalStateT [] $ sequence $ take 5 $ repeat gnextM
```

or:

```
gnextM :: StateT [Generation] IO ()                                         
gnextM = do                                                                 
    b0 <- gets head                                                         
    b1 <- liftIO $ gnext b0                                                 
    modify (b1:)                                                            

runGen :: StateT [Generation] IO a -> Generation -> IO [Generation]         
runGen gnext s = execStateT gnext [s]                                       
                                                                        
test2 = flip runGen [] $ replicateM 5 gnextM
```

depending on what you want.

Comment: Do you mean `sequence $ take 5 $ iterate (gnext =<<) (return [])` evaluates `gnext` 10 times, and your example evaluates it 5 times only?

Comment: @Yuki Yes, it follows from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> following code failed (because of lazy evaluation, I think).

It’s not really due to lazy evaluation. In `test1`, you share the chain of *results* of all the actions, while in `test2`, you only share the actions themselves before sequencing them together, and their results are unrelated:

```
test2 = sequence (take 5 actions)
  where
    actions
      = (return [])
      : [(gnext =<< a) | a <- actions]
```

```
test2 = sequence
  [ return []
  , gnext =<< return []
  , gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
  , gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
  , gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< gnext =<< return []
  ]
```

So the issue is that `sequence (take 5 actions)` doesn’t express the relationship you want, which is something *more like* `fmap (take 5) (sequence actions)`. Unfortunately, that doesn’t produce a result at all, because `sequence` in `IO` is too strict: it tries to consume the infinite stream of `actions` before producing a result at all.

Instead, it’s typical to use patterns such as `tails <$> replicateM 5 randint` when you know the length ahead of time, or combinators like `unfoldrM` if not:

```
test = unfoldrM step (b0, 5)
  where
    b0 = []
    step (b, i)
      | i == 0 = pure Nothing
      | otherwise = do
        b' <- gnext b
        pure (Just (b', (b', i - 1)))

-- Available in ‘monad-loops’ or as below.
unfoldrM
  :: (Monad m)
  => (a -> m (Maybe (b, a))) -> a -> m [b]
unfoldrM f = go
  where
    go a = do
      m <- f a
      case m of
        Just (b, a') -> do
          bs <- go a'
          pure (b : bs)
        Nothing -> pure []
```